# how can we do blameable,sortable,IpTraceable,SoftDeleteable,Uploadable with CodeIgniter,doctrine

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I have integrated doctrine orm in my newly created project with CodeIgniter 2.0 project with this [repo](https://github.com/rubensarrio/codeigniter-hmvc-doctrine) and other sites.  how can we do for blameable,sortable,IpTraceable,SoftDeleteable,Uploadable.

Answer (score 0):

That repo is five years old, no longer supported and the main domain name is dead. You should NOT be using CI2. There have been numerous security fixes and bug fixes and CI3 is supported, maintained and much more powerful. CI2 is buggy, insecure and deprecated.

Comment: Thank you....  for reply,  i download ci_doctine from this link https://github.com/wildlyinaccurate/CodeIgniter-with-Doctrine-2/tree/master/application and i want to  do blameable, sortable, IpTraceable, SoftDeleteable, Uploadable.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that one. Looks much better. Doctrine is excellent and is not too difficult to use in CI. The above code though does some really nice stuff to get it really integrated well, but even without it, using doctrine as a third party app in CI is quite straight forward. Good luck with it...

Comment: i have another question, about many to many relationship of 3 table i done with 2 table but i want do it with 3 table or more then example : table_first   , table_second,   it generate 3 table table_first_second containing primary key of both first and second table.    then what will be the structure of 3 or more tables.actually I want it in doctrine...